# Starting with Android development

Tags: android, layout

Does any one know the best way to learn Android programming quickly?

Will it have been a week now tring to get ahead with the development but I'm always stuck in the GUI part.

P: S I'm not master in Java but I know how to develop what I want to get in one way or other.

Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114287/good-book-for-beginning-android-development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Follow this book](http://download1215.mediafire.com/8b8yzqn0mo4g/pcaas8ec6cgc03y/Beginning+Android+Application+Development_Wei-Meng+Lee.pdf), it will guide you step by step. It has a lot of simple examples also. So that's a good book for learning Android development.

Answer (score 0):

Yow man
I started like 3 months ago with this:
http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6
This is the best for beginners :D

Answer (score 0):

There a lots of resources on the net. My favorite is [The Busy Coders Guide to Android Development](http://commonsware.com/Android/), the great thing about it is that it's a subscription so you will get updated versions which includes new features in Android etc.